# Localization of the Finnish App Store has no effect?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store

Localized my app to Finnish. Decided to change language and region on my Iphone to Finnish and the App Store to the Finnish App store to check out how it looks. To my surprise the Finnish App store is showing the English title, subtitle, Screenshots and description. The keywords seem to be working though. I’ve tried the same method to check out other languages like Spanish and they all work.

Do anyone know why this is the case and if localizing the Finnish app store was no more then money out the window

Comment: Any luck with this ? I am having similar  issue that Finnish and also Slovakian App store page of my app is taking data from English(UK) and not from their localized versions.

Answer (score 0):

In resource folder add finnish language for values folder and put inside string.xml file with finnish language..

Like this way..
folder name = values-fi-rfi

put inside string.xml

```
<string name="yourkey" formatted="false">Hoitaja</string> // value in finnish language
```